# Trying to find out the time between two dates and then making them readable in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, discord.py

Trying to make a discord command to show the amount of time my daughter has been alive

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def luxe(self, ctx):
    currentDate = datetime.utcnow()
    print(currentDate)
    deadline = '08/05/2020 10:05:00'
    deadlineDate = datetime.strptime(deadline, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    print(deadlineDate)
    daysLeft = currentDate-deadlineDate

    years = ((daysLeft.total_seconds()) / (365.242 * 24 * 3600))
    yearsInt = int(years)

    months = (years - yearsInt) * 12
    monthsInt = int(months)

    weeks = (years - yearsInt) * 52
    weeksInt = int(weeks)

    days = (months - monthsInt) * (365.242 / 12)
    daysInt = int(days)

    hours = (days - daysInt) * 24
    hoursInt = int(hours)

    minutes = (hours - hoursInt) * 60
    minutesInt = int(minutes)

    seconds = (minutes - minutesInt) * 60
    secondsInt = int(seconds)

    if yearsInt == 0 and monthsInt == 0:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Luxe Olivia Violet Ellisdon",
                              description=f"She is exactly {weeksInt} weeks, {daysInt} days, {hoursInt} hours, {minutesInt} minutes, {secondsInt} seconds old.",
                              colour=ctx.author.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        embed.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f'You found an easter egg')
        embed.set_image(url='https://i.ibb.co/M1kb2q0/100868516-10158119041366257-6490464808603746304-n.jpg')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif yearsInt == 0:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Luxe Olivia Violet Ellisdon",
                              description=f"She is exactly {monthsInt} months, {weeksInt} weeks, {daysInt}  days, {hoursInt}  hours, {minutesInt} minutes, {secondsInt} seconds old.",
                              colour=ctx.author.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        embed.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_image(url='https://i.ibb.co/M1kb2q0/100868516-10158119041366257-6490464808603746304-n.jpg')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'You found an easter egg')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Luxe Olivia Violet Ellisdon",
                              description=f"she is exactly {yearsInt} years, {monthsInt} months, {weeksInt }weeks, {daysInt}  days, {hoursInt}  hours, {minutesInt} minutes, {secondsInt} seconds old.",
                              colour=ctx.author.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        embed.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_image(url='https://i.ibb.co/M1kb2q0/100868516-10158119041366257-6490464808603746304-n.jpg')
        embed.set_footer(text=f'You found an easter egg')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkt5k.png)

its not quite right and I don't understand why and I would love if someone could explain what it is I am doing wrong. Ived added an edit to it due to the sum being the wrong way around and the deadline being the wrong way around

Comment: Is `deadline` her birthday?  May 8th?  Because August 5, 2020 makes no sense, but you parse the date as %d/%m/%Y.  Also it should be `currentDate - deadlineDate`.

Comment: yeah her birthday is May 8th. I've sorted both things and updated the code, but its still not correct, I just dont understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this function will help you:

```py
def convert_timedelta(duration):
    days, seconds = duration.days, duration.seconds
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    seconds = (seconds % 60)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds
```

Example:

```py
# Your code
currentDate = datetime.utcnow()
deadline = '08/05/2020 10:05:00'
deadlineDate = datetime.strptime(deadline, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
daysLeft = currentDate - deadlineDate
days, hours, minutes, seconds = convert_timedelta(daysLeft) # Use function
print('Days left:', days,
      '\nHours left:', hours,
      '\nMinutes left:', minutes,
      '\nSeconds left:', seconds)
```

Output:

```
Days left: 42
Hours left: 7
Minutes left: 47
Seconds left: 44
```

And then you can use variables `days, hours, minutes, seconds` in your Embed, how you want.

Comment: thanks! that worked amazingly well!
I also need weeks, months and years too tho. How would I get those as well?

Comment: @NathanE Weeks is easy, but months and years are variable numbers of days.